# Anylogic gridCell moveTo

Tags: anylogic

In AniLogic, I've created 144 grid cells using rectangle presentations to represent them. I want to command the agent to move within these cells, but I don't know the exact coordinates of each cell. I've been trying to use "jump to" to skip between cells, but I'm unsure how to proceed in this situation. How can I resolve this?

how jumpTo this gridcell

We try to solve the problem this way to use the A* algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If you use rectangles, you can access the position of each rectangle using `getX()` and `getY()`. These will be the top-left edges of the rectangle.

To get the centroid, you'd need to call `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` on the rectangle as well and compute it.

Then, for your agent, use `jumpTo(x, y)` to make them beam to whatever position you like.

Comment: NOTE: This assumes your agents and rectangles live on the same environment/agent type

Comment: Using the model of analogic cloud RL Pathfinder - A Pathmind Adaptation, we are creating a new model. Here, I used PATHMINDHEPER and moved between cells through do-action. How do I move between cells without using pathmind helper The basic environment is pretty much the same

Comment: isn't Pathmind deprecated?

Comment: Either way, no idea what this has to do with Pathmind. My reply is how you can make agents move to rectangles, which is your original question :) If you actually have a different question, best open a new issue, see some tips for AnyLogic users here: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow